# How can I add only non zero content from text file?

Tags: arrays, list, python-3.x, if-statement, split

I have the following type of data in a text file.

```
15  1  
23  0  
39 -1  
71 -1  
79  1  
95  1  
127 -2  
151  2  
183  1  
191 -1  
239  0  
247  3
```

I want to create a 2d list from the text file as follows. I am able to do that with the code given below with the following result

```
[[15, 1.36896146582243],  
[23, 0.000000000000000],  
[39, 0.848993860380692],  
[71, 0.629227476540724],  
[79, 0.596517662620081],  
[95, 0.543970127117099],  
[127, 1.88189324753006],  
[151, 1.72587115688942],  
[183, 0.391932527534896],  
[191, 0.383636720228727]]
```

However I do not want all the entries, I want only those with non zero entries in 2nd column in my source text file. For example I do not want the entries

```
23  0
239 0
```

How can I add the conditional statement into my code.

```
with open("path.text") as file:
    R = [[int(x) for x in line.split()] for line in file]
```

Comment: `R = [[int(x) for x in line.split()] for line in file if '0' not in line.split()]`.

Comment: @Abdou - that will not capture lines with numbers containing zeros in the first column.

Comment: @Abdou Is it true that will not capture lines with numbers containing zeros in the first column?

Comment: @Kumarm, that was true with the previous version of my comment. But I edited it to make sure that those rows are being captured. So the comment above should work properly.

Comment: @Abdou Thanks...

Comment: @Kumarm - it will still skip adding if the first column is `0`, even if the second one is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to shoehorn it into a single list comprehension expression - it won't be faster in your case:

```
result = []
with open("path.text", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.split()
        if len(line) < 2:  # just to make sure we have both columns
            continue
        column_2 = float(line[1])  # since, it appears, you have floats
        if column_2:
            result.append([int(line[0]), column_2])  # turn column 1 to int, too
```

**UPDATE** - Benchmark time - if you define your functions to closely match each other (so no floats handling or validation as above):

```
def f1():
    with open("path.text", "r") as f:
        return [[int(x) for x in line.split()] for line in f if '0' not in line.split()]

def f2():
    result = []
    with open("path.text", "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.split()
            if line[1] != '0':
                result.append([int(line[0]), int(line[1])])
    return result
```

Where `path.text` contains the same data as in the OP and `assert f1() == f2()` passes, here are some results on my system:

```
 Python 3.5.1, 64-bit
 f1() - 100,000 loops: 10.834s
 f2() - 100,000 loops: 9.9601s

 Python 2.7.11 64-bit
 f1() - 100,000 loops: 6.9243s
 f2() - 100,000 loops: 6.4012s
```

Most of this is actually I/O, the difference in processing is actually far greater in relative terms.

Comment: You said list comprehension expression won't be faster in my case, but your method is taking longer.

Comment: @Kumarm, premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: This is one of those 97% of cases where any optimization you make will have absolutely no effect on the total runtime: make the code readable and well-structured, so you know what you did, and let the I/O-bound task do it's thing. Don't worry about performance here. @Kumarm

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh - I'd argue that a procedural approach, besides giving far more control and validation choices, is also more readable. Being significantly faster (in processing terms) is just an added bonus.

Comment: @zwer, that's what I was arguing. In this case, the two are basically the same performance too, because the I/O is the elephant in the room.

Answer (score 1):

A pythonic solution would be to add an if statement to the list comprehension

```
with open("path.text") as file:
    R = [[int(x) for x in line.split()] for line in file if line[1] != '0']
```